# Create a link dynamically and return back to my page after download

Tags: javascript, performance, navigation-timing-api

I have a html page which takes a url to a file as input from the user. Now I intend to generate a download link dynamically which is straight forward. But I also want to capture the timing information link we get from Performance Timing API using pure javascript.

The timings from [Performance Timing](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html) are specific to page load. So is there a way I can capture this for the download link too?

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: So you want to time how long the download takes? A partial solution would be to use AJAX to download the file into the browser's memory, then have the user save the file from there. You would be able to capture the time when the AJAX request completes, however, you would be likely to encounter cross-origin issues with many urls.

Comment: Yes, I ruled it out due to cross-origin problem